# Eclipse and Android Device Monitor don't start (Java 9, Xubuntu 16.0)

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Android Studio and it's just working fine. 
Android Device Monitor is crashing while it's starting.

I use java version 9 (Oracle Corporation) and the OS is Xubuntu 16.04

Log-File:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
```

After the information that "org.eclipse.core.runtime" can't be resolved, I installed eclipse from the repository.

When I start Eclipse I get similar errors.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.604
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.610
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.617
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.618
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.618
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.619
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.619
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.dist [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.619
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-07-30 12:01:03.630
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Delegating     MethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Is this a known Eclipse + Oracle Java 9 error?
Or a Xubuntu 16.04 error?

Comment: As far as I remember from eclipse stuff, it's because a previous instance of it is running. Try to kill this process from windows task manager and retry (try it when eclipse and studio are down)

Comment: It was not solving the problem. I downloaded the android tools for linux from, without the Android Studio. Probably they changed something in this package, with the new package till yet everything is working fine